# How to create a Dynamic Parameterized SQL Query String in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure-functions, azure-sql-database, prepared-statement

I'm ultimately trying to save a number of records I've stored in a concurrent list within my Function App into a SQL Server database with parameterized values, one of which is an encrypted column (not sure if relevant).

Currently, I'm iterating over each record and extracting the values, parameterizing them, and saving them to the database; doing this for each record. Though, from what I understand this is highly inefficient and I'm told creating a single string with the parameterized values of each record, then running that single string as a SQL Server query would be more efficient.

Could someone explain to me how I might achieve something like this or if I'm perhaps mistaken?

Thank you!

Comment: Use a table valued parameter to send multiple records in one go.

Comment: A table valued parameter would be my first choice, but with 2016+, I tend to opt for passing JSON.  It offers a bit more flexibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`C#`]

You can use `Table-valued parameters` to send multiple rows in a single SQL query.
The flow would be

- Define a `table type`. The schema would be same as the parameters to be inserted.
- Create a `DataTable` with the exact same names and types of the `table type`.
- Pass the `DataTable` as parameter in the query.

Sample

```
CREATE TYPE MyTableType AS TABLE
    ( mytext TEXT,
      num INT );
```

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Sql.ConnectionString")))
{
    connection.Open();

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    // Add columns and rows. The following is a simple example.
    table.Columns.Add("mytext", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("num", typeof(int));
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        table.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString(), DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
    }

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
        "INSERT INTO MyTable(mytext, num) SELECT mytext, num FROM @TestTvp",
        connection);

    cmd.Parameters.Add(
        new SqlParameter()
        {
            ParameterName = "@TestTvp",
            SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured,
            TypeName = "MyTableType",
            Value = table,
            Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
        });

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/performance-improve-use-batching#table-valued-parameters

[`JAVA`]

You can use `PreparedStatement`, create batch of the rows (`ps.addBatch()`) to be inserted and insert batch in one go (`ps.executeBatch()`).

Sample :

```
PreparedStatement ps= con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Sample VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

for(int i; i<10; i++){
  ps.setString(1, "String1");
  ps.setString(2, "String2");
  ps.setString(3, "String3");
  ps.setInt(4, 1000);

  ps.addBatch();
}

ps.executeBatch();
```

If there are a lot of records to be inserted, you can create multiple batches and insert them inside the loop itself.

Comment: @Dai Thank you for pointing it out. I have corrected the answer now.

Comment: Extremely helpful! Thank you very much for taking the time to explain this to me!

Comment: If I already have an existing table which I'm trying to save the records in this new DataTable into, presumably I don't have to CREATE TYPE MyTableType AS TABLE - or am I mistaken? Do I have to create a new table type based on my existing table I'm trying to save to? Thank you!

Comment: @Klh Yes, you will have to create a `table type`. Values will be stored in the created `table type` and that will be passed in the insert statement.
Please refer to the example above and try to create a sample. It will give you more clarity.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get that working yesterday as I realized I would need to create a new type. - I'm just having issues with inserting the encrypted column values because when I was simply using parameterized values I was specifying varchar(100) or varchar(200), however, now I've specified these in my table type but I'm having a clashing issue with varchar and varchar(100) which is my encrypted column for some reason. They're defined the same in the Table Type as they are in the table I'm trying to insert into so I'm not quite sure what the issue there is.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case it helps anyone in the future, I ultimately solved this.

The reason for using SqlBulkCopy is because TVP alone doesn't seem to be compatible with saving to a SQL table containing an Always Encrypted Column. I was receiving some strange Operand Clashing errors despite the types being identically defined. DataTable & TVP don't play nicely with Encrypted Columns it seems.

Using SqlBulkCopy with TVP seems to be the work-around for allowing us to save data from a C# script to a SQL table with Always Encrypted Column(s), using TVP for a single query statement for faster processing times.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(<connection_string>))
{
    connection.AccessToken = new VisualStudioCredential().GetToken()
    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        connection.Open();

    // Create a new DataTable - !Important - We also have to Create Table Type in our Database as mentioned in this thread.
    DataTable saveBatchTable = new DataTable();

    // Add rows to the DataTable
    saveBatchTable.Columns.Add("col_1", typeof(string));
    saveBatchTable.Columns.Add("col_2", typeof(long));
    saveBatchTable.Columns.Add("col_3", typeof(bool));

    // Assuming we have a list of records - for each 'record' in our list...
    foreach (custObject record in recordList)
    {
        // and for each index attribute value within each record object...
        foreach (long idx in record.index)
        {
            // Add a row of values corresponding to the columns previously added
            saveBatchTable.Rows.Add(record.col1Val, record.col2Val, true)
        }
    }

    saveBatchTable.AcceptChanges();

    string stagingTableName = "MyStagingTable"

    // Create an empty temporary table with the headers from your Source  Table within your DB
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * INTO [" + stagingTableName + "] FROM [<SourceTableName>] WHERE 1 = 2;", connection))
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    // Write the DataTable (saveBatchTable) to the new temporary table
    using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
    {
        bulkCopy.DesintationTableName = "[" + stagingTableName + "]";
        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(saveBatchTable);
    }   

    // Store the data within the temporary table to our Source Table then drop the temp table
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("BEGIN TRAN; INSERT [<SourceTableName>] SELECT * FROM [" + stagingTableName + "]; DROP TABLE [" + stagingTableName + "]; COMMIT", connection))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Number of Rows Affected = " +  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString());
    }
    
    connection.Close();

}
```